# Silverlight 4.0: IsolatedStorage URI

Tags: silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage

Is there a way to get the URI of you IsolatedStore?

Comment: http://franksworld.com/blog/archive/2010/01/16/11833.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the physical location to the IsolatedStorage within the file system, I believe the answer is no.

You can, however, get a reference to the IsolatedStorageFile for your application using:

```
IsolatedStorageFile f = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

... and then you can iterate through all of the files within that container:

```
f.GetFileNames();
```

If you can give a little more information about what it is you're actually trying to achieve then perhaps we could suggest a suitable workaround?

Hope this helps.

Comment: i really want to get its absolute URI 

example "c:\<user>..."

Comment: If you *really* need the physical file path, that is possible with .NET reflection. Take a look at the answer to this question for the answer to yours :) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/23ec13d5-6013-4974-b150-649f36d884d0